# Where and How to code my "Invalid Input"

Tags: java, arrays, loops, joptionpane

I need to create a program that will do the following:
    1.) ask user to choose from S, M, L, X
    2.) display the chosen size together with the corresponding price.
    3.) if the input is not exactly the same as what is in the size array, an error message has to be printed. So far I am able to get the user input and display it's corresponding price. However, I'm having a problem with where and how to place the syntax for my error message.

I am only allowed to use import javax.swing.JOptionPane for all of this.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PizzaChoice{
public static void main(String[]args){
    char [] size = {'S','M','L','X'};
    double [] total = {6.99, 8.99, 12.50, 15.00};

    char userInput = ' '; //hold the size that user will choose
    userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sizes Available: S, M, L, X").charAt(0); //ask user to type in his/her choice of pizza size

    for(int i=0; i<size.length; i++){
        if(userInput == size[i]){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userInput+" = "+total[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `flag` to determine if the user has entered the correct input or not.

Your `for` loop can be something like this

```
int flag=0;  //initial value for your flag

 for(int i=0; i<size.length; i++){
        if(userInput == size[i]){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userInput+" = "+total[i]);
            flag=1; //states that user entered correct value
        }
    }

  //check here if user input was correct or not
  if(flag==0){
    //display the error message here
  }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: oh my gosh!!! i didn't know that someone actually replied to my question... thank you so much @Aradhna !!!! my program worked!! *tears of joy* :) .,thank you again!!